# What are the standards for saving a private key?

Tags: java, base64, aes, rsa, private-key

What the title says.

I am generating a private key in java using the Java.security.*

When use the RSA part I generate a public and a private key. The private key I assume from what I have read is encrypted in AES 256bit in order to help keep it secure. Then when it is used it is decrypted.

My question is how are private keys supposed to be stored on the disk?

This is what I think I found out so far...

1. Generate Private Key
2. Encrypt Private Key with AES 256bit using SALT
3. Store Private Key in ASCII Armor Base 64

I was wondering if you should salt anything and how you would store the salt in the key? Also, for encrypting the private key is AES 256bit the standard for most programs?

Thanks!

**Also, how do you store email info, picture... ect?**

Comment: I would use [`java.security.Keystore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). Why can't you?

Comment: @AlistairIsrael very helpful! didn't know about that, but can I export the public and private key with that? I didn't see that option at all in the example they provided... nor on the net which is what I am trying to do